# Connecting to MongoDB from Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

Using Pentaho Data Integration (Spoon) for the first time v. 8.2.

Need to connect to MongoDB data source.

I don't see such an Input Node type and also don't see MongoDB in the Big Data menu.

Any idea how to add the MongoDB input type to the tool or to the Big Data source selector?

Answer (score 0):

I do have MongoDB Input and Output steps under big data collection in my PDI CE 8.2 version, check again:

[image]